# how to establish the length of the data being written by protobuff?

Tags: protobuf-net

I have a `List<T>` where `T` is a fixed width class. It only contains `long` and `int`types.

I am using serialise with position and deserialize with position to be able to append and iterate on the file. (`Serializer.DeserializeItems<T>`) - that works great

Edit:
Taken some time to rethink.
Its probably easier for me to solve the whole thing another way! (updated question title as result)

The outstanding question i do have though and could be very useful is:
How do i know the size of the data written by protobuff?

What I had was an index system pointing to data in another file. I needed a start and length if i was going to protobuff that data file - however I realise now that I can just take a byte[] and be really un-opinionated. Then I already have all the info i need to build the index.

So if i was to protobuff data then I could just write to a memory stream and figure out the length from that and then write that to whatever other stream i have ... Maybe the question has gone away.

@MarcGravell Thanks for your enthusiasm :D

Comment: having only `int` and `long` doesn't make something fixed-width in protobuf... even if they are using fixed-width encoding rather than varint, under proto3 rules, zeros aren't serialized; I'd be concerned about misleading you here, if you're working on a false premise...

Comment: @MarcGravell clever, but I can easily make them non zero. I guess another question would be 'Is there a better way to do this?'

Comment: Adding `bool ShouldSerializeFoo() => true;` would also work to avoid the zero problem. However: do you have a concrete example we can work with here?

Comment: And just to be explicit: protobuf is not *intended* for this scenario. That doesn't mean we *can't*, but it does mean you need to be very careful... hence examples :)

Comment: But (sorry to pepper-dash here): if your type is simple enough, and you need to *force* it to be fixed size, frankly I have ideas on better ways to do this completely, probably involving a struct, spans, and memory-marshal; it'll be tons smaller and faster too

Comment: fine with pepper dashing, my brain works that way. Updated question, hopefully more useful: only question left really is - anyway for protobuff to tell me the length of data added to a stream?

Comment: You can easily measure *individual protobuf messages*, but: there really isn't a concept of "this type of message is N bytes" without data, so there aren't APIs to ask that question. Personally, I don't think this is a great scenario for protobuf, and I say that as someone who loves protobuf. I think there are better ways to implement this, and I've happily walk you through them - but some kind of example would really help set the scene.

Comment: hah, thanks for asking those questions. I don't need length at all. When i looked at the larger business process there was a better way of achieving my goal. Now protobuff feels much more like its working for me rather than me trying to force it.